# Is there any different meaning between using 真 and 真的 in a sentence?

Tags: meaning

I came across some sentences in which `真` or `真的` have been used.

Sentences with `真` only.

```
你真不知道我是谁
这事真不能怪我
```

Sentences with `真的` only.

```
我真的不想去
我真的后悔说过的话
```

Is there any different meaning between using 真 and 真的 in a sentence or it does not matter at all?

Comment: They mean the same.  With 真的, we have more emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

When 真 is used as an **adjective, or adverb** here in all your examples, "的" can sometimes omitted. When "的" is used however..in my personal opinion it just makes the sentence longer and sometimes you could emphasize the tone on "真的".
 When **emphasized in an question**, it'll feel like you're surprised someone really don't know the subject.
 When **emphasized in a plain sentence** it'll feel like you're emphasizing you really don't know it.

But if you're using it as a noun, then it's just "真"
Some examples:#
"不知道這個新聞的真假" (used as noun)
"不知道這個新聞是真的假的" (used as adjective)
"真(的)不知道這新聞的真假" (used as adverb first, then noun at the end)

Answer (score 0):

in both your examples, 真 or 真的 means ‘really’ in english， it is a kind of emphasis, they do not have differences

but you should also notice when meaning 'truth' or 'original'

真的 is adjective， this is true -> 这是真的